# Performance slowdown- mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

My application is deployed on Tomcat with Mysql and Java 8 on a private cloud based server. Today, suddenly the threads connected on the mysql has reached its max limit and is deprecating database performance.

All of a sudden the performance has slowdown, even the insert query is taking 4-5sec. Any clue what to follow to figure this sudden slowdown?

Performance dashboard looks like this, is the innoDB causing the poor performance? My server has 158GB of memory available at the moment: [image: innoDB dashboard]

Comment: Could you provide some examples of queries that slowed down, and their `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, in your post please?

Comment: Hi J.D., it's about each and every query, The query which was taking 1sec is now taking 4-5secs.

Comment: I understand but unfortunately there's not much that can be advised with the information you've provided so far, and having a few examples of what I requested has a good chance at helping determine your issue. Sudden changes to performance without any significant changes to the server or the amount of load applied to the server are usually signs of a software issue - specifically with the database structure and the queries themselves (usually as a result of the data changing over time). And if it's not a database issue, the queries should easily disprove it and help us move onto the next step.

Comment: If you can get online when it happens, capture `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.   If a single-row `INSERT` takes more than milliseconds, then something else is going on -- a back and an `ALTER TABLE are likely suspects.

Comment: Hi Rick, https://ibb.co/VJksb5t here's the show process list of a simple update. There are no alter table commands being executed. I have tried increasing the InnoDB buffer pool and skip-host-cache as well.

Comment: Also, the RAM utilization is 0% and CPU is 100% at the moment.

Comment: Hi J.D, is the screenshot helpful?

Comment: Also, the queries running directly using cron job without web project involvement have slowed down.